# How to add success message after HttpPost submits database changes

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have an `HttpPost` method that add to the database

```
public ActionResult SubmitData(MyViewModel model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var result = submitData(command);

        if (response.success)   
        {
            return RedirectToAction("MyHttpGetMethod");
        }
    }

    return View("MyHttpGetMethod", model);
}

public ActionResult MyHttpGetMethod(int Id)
{
    MyModel model = GetData(Id);

    return View(model);
}
```

After the `HttpPost` is called and the database changes are made successfully, I redirect to 
the `HttpGet` action to get the current data after the changes. I like to display a success message
on the View. I can't use ViewBag because of the Redirect and I can't use TempData, because it's not recommended here.

Comment: Pass a success bool into your MyHttpGetMethod as well as the integer

Comment: Hold on, that won't work, your passing a MyViewModel  into a mthod that accepts a int?! Which is it?

Comment: There are so many different ways of doing this. Instead of `RedirectToAction`, just return a Success view, and then from the Success view redirect to `MyHttpGetMethod`.

Comment: Maybe you can store it in the Session. We use TempData since it allows us to save the info message per request even if different
controllers and actions are invoked per request (-> support child actions) or a http redirect is made (which still is the same request).

Answer (score 0):

TempData is a valid solution for this specific use case. But if you do not prefer to do that, you can pass a querystring value to indicate the status of the transaction from your HttpPost action to the GET action.

So update your GET action to have another paramter

```
public ActionResult MyHttpGetMethod(int Id,string m="")
{
    MyModel model = GetData(Id);
    if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(m) && m=="s")
    {
      // do some code to show the success message here.
      ViewBag.Msg="Saved Successfully";
    }
    return View(model);
}
```

and in your view, use the ViewBag item to show the message (with whatever styles you want)

```
<p>@ViewBag.Msg</p>
```

and in your HttpPost action,

```
return RedirectToAction("MyHttpGetMethod", new { id =model.Id, m="s"} );
```